# Running the Cypress Test Runner Remotely

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, end-to-end

Cypress has a great [test runner](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner.html#Overview) that works really well in the local environment. Although, I haven't found a way to run something like `cypress open` for a remote environment. So is that a way to do this instead of using `cypress run`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You could bundle it in a Docker container that you deploy remotely to run your E2E suite.

Comment: I have a development env running remotely, and I would like to know if there is a way to run my tests with the Test Runner from this env

Comment: As I'm looking for something similar, could you specify whether either cypress or the browser is running on the remote? If you want to connect to a remote browser, possibly [this feature request](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5984) indicates that it is currently not supported. I myself was looking for the other way around as I can only run Cypress on a remote machine but still would like to see the test panel in my local browser somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a local Xserver, you can export the DISPLAY from the remote machine to your local. In my experience it's not very fast, but it's usable.

This is blog post is specific to WSL, but concept (and most of the commands) are the same https://dev.to/nickymeuleman/using-graphical-user-interfaces-like-cypress-in-wsl2-249j